# ASMX web service and error:- The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

i was trying to call a web service running in my asp.net web application project. i search google just with error message and found many link. all people are saying same thing that your web service returning error.

the below ways i try to call web service.

### 1st way

i add service reference of web service in my win form and the call like below way.

```
ServiceReference1.SearchDataIndexSoapClient Client = new ServiceReference1.SearchDataIndexSoapClient();
        ServiceReference1.AuthHeader authHead = new ServiceReference1.AuthHeader();
        authHead.Password = "Admin";
        authHead.Username = "Admin";


        Console.WriteLine(client.StartIndex(authHead));
```

the last line return server 500 error with details text like "The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)"

### 2nd way

i used HttpWebRequest class to call my web service without proxy then also getting same error.

### 3rd way

try to call by fiddler. just give web service url and body. get same error message but when i specify content type text/xml from fiddler then i saw web service works fine and return right result.

**so just not being able to understand that i can call my web service properly by fiddler but when i try to call by HttpWebRequest or adding web reference then getting error. i also set content type = text/xml when used HttpWebRequest  class but no luck.**

please help me to understand the issue and guide me how to fix it for calling by HttpWebRequest  class or by web reference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen all over the web, it is correct that the web service is throwing an error. The Exception you receive about content type is because your service on an error displays a HTML page (text/html) when your web service reference on the client side was expecting a (text/xml). Hope that makes sense!

The root cause, however is an error on your web service. From your code, can you confirm if your web service method is expecting a parameter of type AuthHeader or is it expected in the SoapHeaders.

If it is expecting a parameter of type AuthHeader, put a breakpoint in your web service method or logging to debug further.

Comment: it is solved now. issue was different in my case. there was no problem at web service end rather problem lies at different end. thanks for your time